# Grammar Past Tenses

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect, questions, past-vs-present-perfect

Which one of the following is correct:

1. **Have you remembered** to bring home your football bag?

OR

2. **Did you remember** to bring home your football bag?

Many thanks.

Comment: It would be better if you provide some extra information about which one of them you think is correct. Then the answerer can expand on that view.

Comment: @rjpond I think the question uses simple past and present perfect, not past perfect. I might be wrong also. Informing just in case.

Comment: Thanks @DhanishthaGhosh. You're right, I was mistaken in adding the past-v-past-perfect tag.  I have corrected the tag (now past-vs-present-perfect).

Comment: in my opinion, either one is idiomatic and natural.